# SonataAdmin custom form action

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I am using `SonataAdminBundle` and I'd like to know how to add a custom form action in the `edit` (Something similar to the `Save, Update and Close`)

There doesn't seem to anything documented about it.

I'm trying to add a custom input field that will call a controller or something to update a value and send an email

Is there any docs or examples on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add custom form actions by adding new routes. Because when you add new route you need also add action to handle this route.

#### Create Route

You can register new routes by defining them in your Admin class. Only Admin routes should be registered this way.

The routes you define in this way are generated within your Admin’s context, and the only required parameter to **add()** is the action name. The second parameter can be used to define the URL format to append to **baseRoutePattern**, if not set explicitly this defaults to the action name.

```
<?php
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class MediaAdmin extends Admin
{
        protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $collection->add('myCustomAction');
        $collection->add('view', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/view');
    }
}
```

#### Other steps needed to create your new action

In addition to defining the route for your new action you also need to create a handler for it in your Controller. By default Admin classes use SonataAdminBundle:CRUD as their controller, but this can be changed by altering the third argument when defining your Admin service (in your admin.yml file).

For example, lets change the Controller for our MediaAdmin class to AcmeDemoBundle:MediaCRUD:

```
# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml
sonata.admin.media:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Admin\MediaAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: "Media" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Page
        - 'AcmeDemoBundle:MediaCRUD' # define the new controller via the third argument
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [Acme\DemoBundle]]
```

We now need to create our Controller, the easiest way is to extend the basic Sonata CRUD controller:

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController;

class MediaCRUDController extends CRUDController
{
    public function myCustomAction()
    {
        // your code here ...
    }
}
```

Inside a CRUD template, a route for the current Admin class can be generated via the admin variable’s **generateUrl()** command:

```
<a href="{{ admin.generateUrl('list') }}">List</a>

<a href="{{ admin.generateUrl('list', params|merge('page': 1)) }}">List</a>
```

Just override the template you need and add this custom action.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. I'm having some issues though, I followed your example, changing the media parts with my own orders parts. I added the hyperlinnk to the route. But the problem I have is that I get an error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template `("unable to find the route bm.orders.admin.orders.verify`

Comment: Try writing your route like this:    `<a href="{{ path('admin_acme_demo_foo_list') }}">List</a>`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Although I did have to change and tweak a few bits to get working.