# Custom action in the edit view of sonata admin Bundle

Tags: mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm working with sonata Admin Bundle and I want to add a custom action in the edit view just like ( Update Update and close or Delete). I searched, but I didn't find a solution. I did this before but in the list View.
I have tried to make the same thing in this case by following this answer
[SonataAdmin custom form action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271883/sonataadmin-custom-form-action)
but it does not work and I got this error

> Could not load type "actions"
>   when I add

```
->add('_action', 'actions', array(
        'actions' => array(
            'view' => array('template' => 'ATSAdminBundle:CRUD:form__action_confirmation.html.twig')
            )
        ))
    ;
```

in the

> configureFormFields()

Any one can help me to do this plz ?

Answer (score 3):

This is because `configureFormFields()` doesn't accept this entry. You can do this only in `configureListFields()`.

If you want to add an action in the edit form, like the buttons: "Update", "Update and close" or "Delete", then you have to override the following template:

`vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/base_edit_form.html.twig`

Copy this file in `app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/CRUD`

and add your action in the `{% block formactions %}`, something like this:

```
{% if admin.hasroute('view') %}
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('view', object) }}">View</a>
{% endif %}
```

This is just an example to point you to the right direction. You have to adapt it.

Good luck!